# TextView or Layout stay at the bottom of a <fragment>

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can i make a view stay at the bottom of a fragment. in the code below i have LinearLayout with a map fragment, inside the fragment there an EditText to center at the top of the fragment. How can i add a Textview right after the

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:hint="Search"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>


</fragment>
//How can i make these Text view to the buttom
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/bgprofil"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
```

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` is attribute use with RelativeLayout
`android:gravity` is only affected with the text inside the TextView

If you want to put TextView below EditText, please put the TextView in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `android:layout_weight="1"` so the fragment view will occupy the available space of your LinearLayout, so the textView will remain in the bottom

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:hint="Search"
            />



    </RelativeLayout>


</fragment>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/bgprofil"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have tried that but it did not work. Trying to achieve something like the image in the link  [image](http://imgur.com/a/7mddD)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach to reach your desired design if you're not strict about your view groups.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:hint="Search for Address"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/bgprofil"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

in Linearlayout using `android:gravity` attribute you can get your desire view.

in your case you want your text view below the fragment and bottom of the of screen, 
in that case :

1 `android:weightSum=1` in Parent linearlayout

2 `android:weight=0.9` in fragment

3 `android:weight=0.1` in textview

using this method you get your desire view for any screen size.